# Store JSON data outside of _v property in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I'm using MongoDB as a database for my web application. I'm looking for a way to insert and retrieve dynamic JSON data without making any typed classes for it.

My web application sends a JSON string. Then in the backend I convert that JSON string to a `BsonDocument` and insert that into MongoDB:

```
var obj = BsonDocument.Parse(json.ToString());
Db.GetCollection<dynamic>("Items").InsertOneAsync(obj);
```

This works fine, except that the structure in MongoDB looks like this:

```
_id = ObjectId("55618d35d747199c0a486fe0")
_t = MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson
_v = (3 fields)
   username = "JohDoe"
   password = "xxxxx"
   email = "em@il.com"
```

In other words, my JSON object is stored inside `_v`. I don't want to store everything in a "sub" property. I want it to look like this:

```
_id = ObjectId("55618d35d747199c0a486fe0")
_t = MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson
username = "JohDoe"
password = "xxxxx"
email = "em@il.com"
```

Is it possible to store the data like that without creating any typed objects my self?

Answer (score 4):

Using GetCollection<dynamic> is equivalent to using GetCollection<object>, and when the type of the collection is object then every value needs to be stored with a _t and a _v field. The _t field represents the type, and the _v field represents the value.

Can you use GetCollection<BsonDocument> instead? That would result in the documents being stored directly with no need for _t and _v fields.

Comment: Using GetCollection<BsonDocument> worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to fix the issue I am using:

`GetCollection< BsonDocument >` to insert new documents.

`GetCollection< dynamic >` to query the DB.